# Get Attributes of window.getSelection().anchorNode

Tags: javascript, html, text, selection

`window.getSelection().anchorNode` returns quite a lot of details about the node where the user clicked to start the selection, but how can I get attributes of that text node, like `class`, `id` etc.?

Example:

```html
<span id="word1">Aaa</span>
<span id="word2">Bbb</span>
```

The user selects something of these two spans and I need to know where he started the selection, whether in `#word1` or in `#word2`

Comment: `text node` has `class`and `id`?

Comment: A text `node` can't have a `class` or `id`

Comment: @xianshenglu I think so, if it is something like `<span id="myText" class="grey-text">Something</span>` ...

Comment: No, even in this case, the TextNode `Something` will just be a child of the Span#myText Element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since **[textNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) do not have any attributes** you will have to get the attributes from the element parent. The [`select event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/select) has spotty support so I used the [`mousedown event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) and registered the [Document Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) to listen for it. In order to control where and when you get values from among 100 possibilities (remember the Document Object will be aware of `mousedown` event on anything but the Window Object), we must establish 2 things:

1. **Event.currentTarget:** A property of the **Event Object**, that represents the element registered to the event. In the **Demo** **[`e.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)** is the Document Object (`document`.)
2. **Event.target:** A property of the **Event Object** that represents the origin of an event, which is fancy talk for the element that was clicked, changed, hovered over, etc. In the **Demo** **[`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)** is basically anything in the `document`.

The following **Demo** demonstrates a way to get the id and/or classes of a clicked element node.

### Demo

**Details are commented in Demo**

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', showAttr, false);

function showAttr(e) {
  // if the node clicked is NOT document...
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    /* if the clicked node has a class attribute...
    || log all of its classes in console
    */
    var tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.hasAttribute('class')) {
      var cList = tgt.classList;
      console.log('class=' + cList);
    }
    /* if the clicked node has an id...
    || log its id in console
    */
    if (tgt.hasAttribute('id')) {
      console.log('id=' + tgt.id);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 70%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

main,
main * {
  outline: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<main id='base'>
  <h1 class='mainHeading'>Title</h1>

  <ol class='ordered list'>
    <li class='1'>One</li>
    <li class='2'>Two</li>
    <li class='3'>Three</li>
  </ol>
  Text
  <article id='post31' class='test'>
    <h2 class='postHeading'>Title</h2>
    <p class='content text'>Post content</p>
    article text
  </article>
</main>





</main>
```

Answer (score 6):

guess you need this:`window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode`

```js
window.onclick = function() {
  console.log(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode)
  console.log(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.className);
  console.log(window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode.id)
}
```

```html
<p class="cls" id="p1">p tag with class="cls" and id="p1",try to select something</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a while ago but I found a way to do this, you can access the attribute by doing the following:

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement.getAttribute('your-attribute-name')
```

This will get the DOM element that surrounds the selected text and with access to the DOM element you can retrieve it's attributes.